# Google Tag Manager script issue related to scroll

Tags: jquery, magento-1.9, google-tag-manager

Google tag manager script(`gtm.js`) is showing an error on my chrome console(*attached at the end*). It's a magento store. Shop uses `jQuery` library along with `prototype` js. 
This tag manager script is being included in `Miscelleanous scripts` section from `System -> Configuration -> Design`. I have tried both footer script and head script section. But both positions result in the same issue.

Need help in debugging this because stack trace in console is not very helpful either.

[image]

Comment: Since prototype and jQuery both use the $ variable I would assume that jQuery is set to noconflict mode. Can you try and replace $(..).scroll with jQuery(...).scroll ?

Comment: GTM script is being added on run time. I have no control on it. Trying to look at the source code to get any clues. I'll be somewhat surprised if they haven't handled it already.

Comment: This is not a GTM issue, it is a jQuery issue, even if the code is deployed via GTM. jQuery and Prototype compete for the "$" als their function name, and so Magneto often sets jQuery to "noconflict" mode, which changes the global variable to "jQuery". If a custom HTML tag inside GTM is not aware of that it might try to use the jQuery scroll function but ends up calling an (undefined) function in prototype. That is why changing the call to jQuery(...).scroll _might_ help.

Comment: @EikePierstorff to change the call to jQuery I would have to change the gtm.js file itself. And this file is being added dynamically by google tag manager tracking script. I think that I understand what you just said about the noconflict mode. So the code inside GTM is checking for $.scroll function availability. So isn't it possible to only check for jQuery.scroll availability? My assumption here is that jQuery will always point to same object as $ does irrelevant of noconflict mode?

Comment: No, you have to change the tags configured in GTM. GTM does not by itself make calls to jQuery. The error is displayed as part of the gtm.js file because GTM wraps the configured tags into a big javascript file and downloads it to your page - that is why the console show the gtm.js file as the source, but the solution is still to go to the gtm interface, search for custom html tags and change or disable the tag that makes the erronous call. Your page will then download the changed file and the problem should be gone.

Comment: Aah! So behaviour is controlled from tag manager console. Let me pass on this information to relevant people. Thanks for pointing that out to me!